# Rails 5 generator db:rollback does nothing although is called before deleting migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-generators

I'm probably misunderstanding something with the rails generators workflow, but after several days searching through the code and documentation, I can't find a solution for the problem.

I made a custom scaffold generator for adding some extra files and run the generated migration right after the scaffold files are created.
With the same approach i'm trying to rollback the migration as the first thing when ***rails destroy my_scaffold*** command is executed in order to rollback before the migration file is deleted.

my custom generator code **scaffold_meta.rb**, wich runs the db:migrate command after the migration file is created. This is the working part.

```
require 'generators/resource/resource_generator'
module Rails
  module Generators
    class ScaffoldMetaGenerator < ResourceGenerator # :nodoc:
      remove_hook_for :resource_controller
      remove_class_option :actions

      class_option :stylesheets, type: :boolean, desc: "Generate Stylesheets"
      class_option :stylesheet_engine, desc: "Engine for Stylesheets"
      class_option :assets, type: :boolean
      class_option :resource_route, type: :boolean
      class_option :scaffold_stylesheet, type: :boolean
      class_option :steps, type: :boolean, default: 'step'

      def handle_skip
        @options = @options.merge(stylesheets: false) unless options[:assets]
        @options = @options.merge(stylesheet_engine: false) unless options[:stylesheets] && options[:scaffold_stylesheet]
      end

      hook_for :scaffold_controller, required: true

      hook_for :assets do |assets|
        invoke assets, [controller_name]
      end

      hook_for :stylesheet_engine do |stylesheet_engine|
        if behavior == :invoke
          invoke stylesheet_engine, [controller_name]
        end
      end

      def mirate_if_invoke
        if behavior == :invoke
          say behavior.to_s + ' migrate', :green
          rake("db:migrate --trace")
        end
      end

      invoke 'step'

    end
  end
end
```

previous code ends up calling my custom **model_generator.rb**, which tries to rollback before deleting the migration file.

```
require 'rails/generators/model_helpers'

module Rails
  module Generators
    class ModelGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase # :nodoc:
      include Rails::Generators::ModelHelpers

      def rollback_if_revoke
        if self.behavior == :revoke
          say behavior.to_s + ' rollback', :red
          rake("db:rollback --trace")
        end
      end

      argument :attributes, type: :array, default: [], banner: "field[:type][:index] field[:type][:index]"
      hook_for :orm, required: true, desc: "ORM to be invoked"
    end
  end
end
```

output of the generator with revoke behavior shows how **rake db:rollback** is suposedly called but has no effect.

```
$rails d  scaffold_meta pez edad:integer nombre

Running via Spring preloader in process 8888

***revoke rollback

    rake  db:rollback --trace***
  invoke  active_record
  remove    db/migrate/20161013145014_create_pezs.rb
  remove    app/models/pez.rb
  invoke    rspec`
```

Any help would be very apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same challenge in Rails 4.7.0.

I noticed that `rake db:rollback` worked when the `behavior == :invoke` but did nothing when `behavior == :revoke`.

Looking at the `rake` method source:

```
  # GEMDIR/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/generators/actions.rb:

  # Runs the supplied rake task
  #
  #   rake("db:migrate")
  #   rake("db:migrate", env: "production")
  #   rake("gems:install", sudo: true)
  def rake(command, options={})
    log :rake, command
    env  = options[:env] || ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || 'development'
    sudo = options[:sudo] && RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] !~ /mswin|mingw/ ? 'sudo ' : ''
    in_root { run("#{sudo}#{extify(:rake)} #{command} RAILS_ENV=#{env}", verbose: false) }
  end
```

The `run` method called in the block passed to `in_root` is from the `Thor::Actions` module:

```
# GEMDIR/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:

# Executes a command returning the contents of the command.
#
# ==== Parameters
# command<String>:: the command to be executed.
# config<Hash>:: give :verbose => false to not log the status, :capture => true to hide to output. Specify :with
#                to append an executable to command execution.
#
# ==== Example
#
#   inside('vendor') do
#     run('ln -s ~/edge rails')
#   end
#
def run(command, config = {})
  return unless behavior == :invoke

  destination = relative_to_original_destination_root(destination_root, false)
  desc = "#{command} from #{destination.inspect}"

  if config[:with]
    desc = "#{File.basename(config[:with].to_s)} #{desc}"
    command = "#{config[:with]} #{command}"
  end

  say_status :run, desc, config.fetch(:verbose, true)

  unless options[:pretend]
    config[:capture] ? `#{command}` : system("#{command}")
  end
end
```

The first line in the method, `return unless behavior == :invoke` short circuits the call to execute the original `rake 'db:rollback'` command.

Railties also has an `Actions` module (`Rails::Generators::Actions`) which seems to follow Thor's `invoke` \ `revoke` logic. So I've concluded that it's best just not to try rollback when the generator is in the `:revoke` state.

I've ended up following the Rails convention to generate a migration file on `:invoke`, and destroy it on `:revoke` and rely on the user to manually execute `rake db:migrate` or `rake db:rollback` when needed.

Hope that helps.